# Placing a manufactured (tiny) home / RV, trailer foundation on stands or blocks

Tags: concrete, foundation, beam, footings, pier-blocks

What are the best practices in placing a fairly temporary, a few years with full time use, 10K lb manufactured home/ rv with a trailer foundation on stands/blocks in the western pacific cascades?

Unit currently sits on a few cinder blocks that lie flat on the ground soil.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the wheels are still under it why not support it with blocks or rail road ties. We don't have many earth quakes here. My travel trailer sat on 4 scissor jacks for several years with only 2x6" under the jacks (and tires to keep them out of the mud) while we were remodeling that house through 2 winters with no problems at all.

Comment: Please simplify your post to ask one clear question. Post additional questions if you like. We aren't a discussion forum, and your question would require a book to answer fully.

Comment: Hopefully that helps. Trying to get any quality advice, perhaps that points to books or articles